# Return all filename from database by specific field name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write function which will get all `filename` for particular `job_id`.

**DATABASE: analytics_report**

```
| id | job_id | filename |
|----|--------|----------|
| 1  | abcd   | file1    |
| 2  | abcd   | file2    |
| 3  | bcde   | file3    |
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
@$job_id = $request->job_id;
$filename = array();


}
```

Example:

If user selects `job_id` = abcd then `filename` variable in controller should have an array of files from Database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In namespace add

```
use DB;
```

then in method add table name,

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
  $job_id = $request->job_id;
  $filename = DB::table('table_name')->where('job_id',$job_id)->get()->pluck('filename')->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Query**

```
   public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
  $job_id = $request->job_id;
  $file = DB::table('table_name')->where('job_id','=',$job_id)->select('filename')->get()->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In namespace

```
use DB;
```

in download method:

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
  $job_id = $request->job_id;
  $filenames = DB::table('analytics_report')->where('job_id',$job_id)->pluck('filename');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DB class to do this:

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
    $job_id = $request->job_id;
    $filenames = DB::table('analytics_report')->select('filename')
                  ->where('job_id', $job_id)->get()->toArray();

}
```

Alternatively, if you already have a model for the analytics_report and assuming your model is `AnalyticsReport`, you could that with:

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{
    $job_id = $request->job_id;
    $filenames = AnalyticsReport::select('filename')
                  ->where('job_id', $job_id)->toArray();

}
```